# CCTV housing that fits the Raspberry PI

Tags: camera

I'm looking for a CCTV housing that fits the Raspberry PI and the camera board in for under £10 (or very near to £10).

It needs to be:

- waterproof / made waterproof with silicon sealant
- at least 160mm x 70mm x 30mm (to incorporate the SD card and USB
  connector)

I would prefer a dome type, but am really struggling to find one that fits.

Because these things are sold as "dummy" devices, the dimensions, and information about them, are not always detailed enough to know if it'll fit.

I've tried [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Dummy-CCTV-Camera-Great-Value-Deterrent-/260647431767?pt=UK_CCTV&hash=item3cafcc2e57) but it didn't fit, thus I've sent it back today frustrated; so i thought i'd ask for links to housings that people have tried themselves, thus know will fit a Raspberry PI with SD card and USB connector.

[this one didn't quite fit too](https://www.3720.co.uk/blog/rpi-security-cam/)

There must be one out there that fits, and someone must have done this.

Comment: Hi Reggie. I am sorry but asking advice on the best product for whatever is not allowed on most Stack Exchanges, since they are primarily opinion based and there cannot be one good answer. Also, you do not need to formally finish your question with a signature ant advanced thanks. Please upvote and accept answers as thanks. Its a good question, just against site rules to ask it here.

Comment: Hi Ppumkin, I understand about "formally finishing" and stack exchange sites, Point noted! But not so in agreement about which product. I was asking which product has someone FIT a PI into. This is not opinion based, but specification based, on size and price. But i understand what you are getting at :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is, what you are trying to do is find an existing CCTV camera enclosure and stick a Pi (and possibly a camera) inside. This has the issue that the Pi or camera module (*with incredibly easy to break cable)* may be damaged due to being forced into it, as well by it getting wet due to being outdoors in not-well designed case, or overheating (fairly unlikely).

Ideally, you need to get an existing case for the best performance - the problem here is, its fairly unlikely you can get anything under £20 *(normal Pi cases can be fairly expensive anyway :( ... )*

For instance, you can get [this case](https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi-camera/nwazet-pi-camera-box-bundle) from ModMyPi:

[image: Nwazet Pi Camera Box Bundle (Case, Lens & Wall Mount)]

The problem here is, mainly the price (pretty much £25), as well as the fact all those holes don't look waterproof...

Another choice could be [PiCE](http://elsondesigns.com/pice-raspberry-pi-camera-enclosure), a apparently waterproof and rugged case, funded by [this Kickstarter campaign](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1821240043/pice-the-ultimate-case-for-your-raspberry-pi-and-c) (with promotional video).

[image: PiCE]

It looks quite good compared to the other case, as it has heat sinks, waterproof assembly, removable sides, holes to attach to things - it also looks like it can be mounted on a tripod (whether you would need to but it from them i don't know)

There is also an [outdoor version](http://ed-venture.biz/pice/outdoor-pice-metal-raspberry-pi-computer-enclosure.html), which has RF transparent (WiFi etc can go through) rubber gaiter to protect connectors going into the back of the case. A [weather shield](http://ed-venture.biz/weather-shield.html) is also available (for £10!!!). Doing it with this would also likely get fairly expensive with all the extras.

There are many other cases, most of which are even more expensive, and are not waterproof...

The thing I would do (doesn't mean you have to do it - I actually had a go at this until i got bored and started on a Pi based Robot instead), would have a USB webcam with a fairly long cord *(could also be linked wirelessly, those can be a bit less reliable, and cord will be required for power to the camera anyway)* linked to the Pi, which could be either indoors in a standard case, or just attached in a plain box on wall (a [1.75 litre Really Useful Box](http://www.reallyusefulproducts.co.uk/uk/html/onlineshop/rub/b01_75litre.php) and a few carefully drilled holes worked fine for this (two for USB power in, and USB camera out), plus some 90 degree corner brackets.

With the price of the box (£4 tops, can't remember) plus the brackets, with no cost for the camera (3MP internal USB camera out of an old netbook + old USB cable from a broken camera), I think I did this under £10 (not including the Pi and stuff I had got previously).

Oh and one last thing, if you have a microSD card you can use, you can use [this](https://www.modmypi.com/sd-cards-and-adaptors/raspberry-pi-micro-sd-card-adaptor) to fit it into the Pi flush to the edge of the board, meaning there is no sticking out SD card to get in the way.

> **Note**
>   Quite a large chunk of the above is opinion based - sorry....
>   Even then, everything seems to get fairly expensive.

Comment: Hi Wilf, Thanks for your comments, but all the concerns you have probably could be worked around, apart from price. I know the PI is more than an ip based CCTV camera, but some people are using it for that, and more. Therefore it would be nice if there could be a waterproof enclosure that, along withe the PI, camera and case, would match a standard IP based cameras price. It must be possible, someone must have done it :)

Answer (score 2):

This is [the one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0095RE0K0/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=B0095RE0K0&linkCode=as2&tag=raspberrypi06-21) mentioned on the raspberry pi blog:

Comment: its mentioned here: http://www.raspberrypi.org/turn-your-pi-into-a-low-cost-hd-surveillance-cam/ - based on [this blog post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/665518/Raspberry-Pi-as-low-cost-HD-surveillance-camera) which used [this one](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B006OKN3TK/ref=as_li_qf_sp_asin_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1638&creative=6742&creativeASIN=B006OKN3TK&linkCode=as2&tag=scavisoftw-21)